# virtualmin + nginx without php

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, virtualmin

how to setup **virtualmin** + **nginx** for static files hosting only
and should not show or run .php files 
i want to setup this server just for static files and without php

how to set config for automatically Create Virtual Server
 - without php
 - Nginx
 - just show jpg/html/gif/png/css

Comment: You want to set this config for all domains or just one special domain?

Comment: @Mostafa for all domains

Comment: I think serverfault is better place for this question .

Comment: While Server Fault might be a better site in theory, I'm not sure that this question would meet their quality standards.